# Trying to find smallest positive number for float, double, long double. Works for double and long double but fails for float

Tags: c++, while-loop, floating-point, comparison

I'm trying to find the biggest and smallest number for each data type (float, double and long double). I'm using a `while` loop and I'm comparing every value with infinity (for biggest number) and 0 (for smallest). Then it prints the found values. It gives me correct values for double and long double and biggest number in float type is also correct.

However, for smallest float, it prints 0. When I modify the program to show every value in cycle, the correct value is the second last but  after that, for some reason, the cycle goes once again, says that 0 > 0 and prints 0 as smallest value.

I dont understand, why is this happening? Even if the last value was so small that it is rounded to 0, why does it then decide that 0 > 0 and lets the cycle go one last time?

Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float big_f = 1, small_f = 1;
    double big_d = 1, small_d = 1;
    long double big_ld = 1, small_ld = 1;

    while(!(isinf(big_f*2)))
    {
        big_f *= 2;
    }

    while((small_f*0.5)>0 and !((small_f*0.5)==0))
    {
        small_f *= 0.5;
    }

    cout << "Najmensie cislo float je "<< small_f << endl;
    cout << "Najvacsie cislo float je "<< big_f << endl;

    while(!(isinf(big_d*2)))
    {
        big_d *= 2;
    }

    while((small_d*0.5)>0)
    {
        small_d *= 0.5;
    }

    cout << "Najmensie cislo double je "<< small_d << endl;
    cout << "Najvacsie cislo double je "<< big_d << endl;

    while(!(isinf(big_ld*2)))
    {
        big_ld *= 2;
    }

    while((small_ld*0.5)>0)
    {
         small_ld *= 0.5;
    }

     
    cout << "Najmensie cislo long double je "<< small_ld << endl;
    cout << "Najvacsie cislo long double je "<< big_ld << endl;
}
```

Note, this is for school, and I can't just compare it with `FLT_MIN`.

Comment: *I'm trying to find biggest and smallest number for each data type* -- That is all done by [<limits>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).  There is no need to invent your own code to do this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was about to answer the same, but if FLT_MIN (from "C") can't be used I don't think `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` will be acceptable either.

Comment: A multiplication of one `float` with one `double` results in the `float` being promoted to `double` and the resulting expression being of type `double`, so you don't use a comparison of 2 `float`s in `(small_f*0.5)>0`, but effectively the same as `(static_cast<double>(small_f) * 0.5) > 0`

Comment: Use 0.0f, 0.5f when you are working with floats. 0.0 and 0.5 are doubles.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/denorm_min  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min https://godbolt.org/z/1n9hPYh7a

Comment: *And please, this is for school, i cant just compare it with FLT_MIN* -- I'm really wondering why a school is wasting the student's time on this, unless this is some really deep "compiler intrinsics" course you're taking.  To add, even if you got this to "work", compare your answers to what actually is returned when using `std::numeric_limits`.  Are they the same?  If not, then either your code is wrong, and/or you can't get the true answers from writing `while` and `for` loops.

Comment: It's not doable without `limits` header (assuming you don't want to use platform- and compiler-specific features, likely doing UB in process), because [floating point math is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: BTW it doesn't crashes it gives wrong result. Problem is for `float` you are doing calculation on `double` since you multiply of type `float` and `double` give outcome which type is `double`. Fixed: https://godbolt.org/z/qEfjGhM4r

Comment: *It is supposed to work.* -- Unless you have a debug build, and `assert(myComputedMaxValue == std::numeric_limits<double>::max());`, `assert(myComputedMinValue == std::numeric_limits<double>::min());`, and all of the other `assert`'s not mentioned, then this will not "work" until you get that program to run through all of the asserts without firing any of them.  And maybe your teacher is going to use that same test on your program, even though you say you can't use `FLT_MIN`.

Comment: *It gives me correct values for double and long double and biggest number in float type is also correct.* -- Prove this by doing what I mentioned in my last comment.  Did you do an `assert()` with the `FLT_MIN`, `FLT_MAX`, etc. to ensure that your computed values are indeed the minimum and maximum?

Comment: Your general approach won't give correct answers because of subnormals. Even if you have a proper algorithm, you need to cast all of your expressions to the correct type and make sure that arithmetic is performed in the correct type. Then you'll need to be aware that compilers are permitted to do several implementation-defined and possible non-deterministic optimizations around floating-point arithmetic that e.g. permit them to use higher-precision intermediate results than the actual types of the expressions would permit.

Comment: I guess we need platform and compiler details. E.g. DBL_MIN == LDBL_MIN in MSVC and we need to know whether it is an assignment to calculate with the minimal numbers with exponent-mantissa calculation.

Comment: `FLT_MIN` is minimum possible normalized value. For denormalized values `FLT_TRUE_MIN` can be used. Also it is possible to construct any IEEE 754 minimum possible denormalized value by setting all bits to 0 but fraction less significant bit to 1.

Comment: @user17732522: Re “Your general approach won't give correct answers because of subnormals”: The problem statement says to find the smallest number for each type. Presumably that means the smallest magnitude non-zero number, which is a subnormal (in formats that have subnormals), which this approach will find (for formats using two as a base). The problem statement does not say to find the smallest normal or to find `FLT_MIN`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah yes, I didn't read the problem statement correctly.

Answer (score 2):

`0.5` is a `double` constant, so `small_f*0.5` converts `small_f` to `double` and uses `double` for the arithmetic. Then `(small_f*0.5)>0` tests whether `small_f` has yet reached the point where a `double` reaches zero.

To fix that, change `0.5` to `0.5f` wherever you use it with a `float`. Alternatively, use `small_f/2` and let the `int` `2` be converted to `float`.

Additionally, the C++ standard allows implementations to use more precision than the nominal type when evaluating expressions, so, for example, `x*y` may be evaluated with `double` or `long double` arithmetic even if `x` and `y` are `float` or may be evaluated with `long double` even if `x` and `y` are `double`. To guard against this, assign the value to an object or perform a cast, which is required to “discard” excess precision: `(float) (small_f/2) > 0`.

Comment: "_To guard against this, assign the value to an object or perform a cast, which is required to “discard” excess precision_": Be careful though that compilers may not follow the standard here correctly by default. E.g. GCC with default settings ignores the standard-required rounding on casts. `-fexcess-precision=standard` or one of the `-std=c++XX` flags (_not_ `-std=gnu++XX`) must be given for it to follow the standard here. Similarly GCC by default performs floating point expression contraction across statements, so `-ffp-contract=off` might be needed as well. I haven't tested Clang/MSVC.

Comment: Also, how the excess precision is discarded should be dependent on the rounding mode I guess. So I am not sure that it is guaranteed to round to `0` where expected.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but if I were trying to learn about floating point numbers, I would look at how they are represented: the IEEE format in particular -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754, and see if I can get the answer by coding inspired by the specification. Floating point numbers are essentially sign * fraction * exponent, and understanding this is very helpful indeed when doing numerical work.

E.g. to get the highest floating point number, `FLT_MAX`, I wrote this.

```
float largest_floating_point()
{
    const unsigned mantissa_index = 0;
    const unsigned exponent_index = 23;
    const unsigned sign_index = 31;

    // maximise mantissa
    // E.g. here we subtract 1 from binary 1,00000000 to get binary 0,11111111
    const unsigned mantissa = (1 << (exponent_index - mantissa_index)) - 1;
    // maximise exponent
    const unsigned num_nan_bits = 1;
    const unsigned exponent = (1 << (sign_index - exponent_index)) - 1 - num_nan_bits;
    // sign is zero for largest number
    const unsigned sign = 0;

    // combine by shifting and ORing bits together
    const unsigned bit_pattern =
        (mantissa << mantissa_index) | (exponent << exponent_index) | (sign << sign_index);

    // cast to float -- go via array of bytes to avoid arithmetic conversion
    static_assert(sizeof(unsigned) == sizeof(float));
    union
    {
        unsigned u;
        float f;
    } n;
    n.u = bit_pattern;
    return n.f;
}
```

This doesn't follow your approach of using loops, and nor is it a program one would want to use in production, not least because the casting is strictly speaking undefined. But this works on both Visual C++ (Windows) and gcc (linux).

And I learnt a lot from doing it, and from writing the code for `FLT_MIN` (not shown). I've been programming a long while and thought I understood floating point representations very well. It turned out I didn't, and learnt something :).

If you choose to explore this approach to get the limits, do pay careful attention to the specification, in particular to "bias" in the main article, how NaNs are represented (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), and how zero is represented (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero).

Comment: "_But this works on both Visual C++ (Windows) and gcc (linux)_": It isn't valid on GCC without the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag. GCC will make use of the type aliasing restrictions for optimization by default.

Comment: @user17732522 Turns out the build failure on gcc release was `'array' is used uninitialized` -- I assumed the code would also produce the wrong number. Turning warnings as errors off, the tests for smallest and largest floating point numbers passed. I take the point about aliasing though -- I had to get this right some years ago and had completely forgotten how awkward it is.

Comment: The warning is a result of GCC's internal analysis determining that `array` can't have been written to in `((unsigned*)array)[0] = bit_pattern;` because that is operating on an `unsigned`, not a `float` that is being read from it. GCC will not only use that deduction for producing diagnostics, but also for optimization.

Comment: On my machine at least, gcc produces the warning, and the compiled code produces the result that I wanted; clearly it is unsafe, however. But, the point of the answer is to learn about floating point representations -- aliasing and compiler optimizations are a whole nother thing -- when I worked on code where this mattered, I learnt enough to realize how little I really knew.

Comment: `union { uint32_t u; float f; } n; n.u = 1; printf("%Le\n", (long double)n.f);`

Comment: @dimich perfect, thank you, amended answer, now builds and tests with no warnings on gcc release as well as debug (and clang)